# Is it possible to source a vitualenv in a shell script and then have the shell that executes the script run in the new env?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Is it possible to run a shell script that sources my python `virtualenv` and then have the shell be in the new environment?

Here is my shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function createProject() {

    if [ -e $1 ]
    then
        rm -r ./$1
    fi

    if [ -e env-$1 ]
    then
        rm -r ./env-$1
    fi

    virtualenv ./env-$1
    django-admin startproject $1
}

createProject $1

source ./env-$1/bin/activate

exit 1
```

I then run `./script.sh hello-world`. 
Basically if I were to run `source ./hello-world/bin/activate` my shell the virualenv would be activated and the shell would then be running in the new environment. 
How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is possible using shell functions only, as they do not spawn separate processes.
The problem with your approach is that the virtualenv is activated in a sub-process that was created to run the shell script.

Instead of having a executable shell script, do like this:

```
function createProject() {

    if [ -e $1 ]
    then
        rm -r ./$1
    fi

    if [ -e env-$1 ]
    then
        rm -r ./env-$1
    fi

    virtualenv ./env-$1
    django-admin startproject $1

    source ./env-$1/bin/activate
}
```

Save this as createProject.sh and source this file in .bashrc or .bash_profile

```
source createProject.sh
```

This way the virtualenv is activated in the current process.